# Is it possible to make Websocket as a REST instead of SOAP????

Tags: html, wcf, rest, websocket

Is there any way to make a websocket as a REST service and host it in IIS..IIS8 only supports websocket with NetHttpBinding. and access from a client who has a proxy implemented for the service...But I want to have Websocket with REST..so that I can access that service from my android App and my HTML5 Client. Is that possible..???

I have a rest service in my project which serves data as per requirement.
   1.RegisterTag(TagName);
   2.value GetValue();

Now I have to have a callback from the service. First I have to call the RegisterTag(MyTagName). and then I should get notification from the server side.It is implemented with the Server sent events. But now I need to convert this REST service to websocket.

So, is it possible to add REST feature in WebSocket ?? I am planning to add NetHttpBinding in my new implementation.

Thanks 
Arijit

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this 
[Is ReST over websockets possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373734/is-rest-over-websockets-possible)

http://www.kimchy.org/rest_and_web_sockets/

Comment: The second link is dead

Answer (score 0):

REST does not require any specific protocol so it is possible to use websockets if you like.

*"One thing that confuses people, is that REST and HTTP seem to be hand-in-hand. After all, the world-wide-web itself runs on HTTP, and it makes sense, a RESTful API does the same. However, there is nothing in the REST constraints that makes the usage of HTTP as a transfer protocol mandatory. It's perfectly possible to use other transfer protocols like SNMP, SMTP and others to use, and your API could still very well be a RESTful API"*

http://restcookbook.com/Miscellaneous/rest-and-http/