# How to write webSockets for Rest calls in Spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I'm new to web socket programming. I have more than 10 methods annotated with `@GetMapping`, where the returned data is read from a MySQL database.

Can anyone help me to know how to write WebSockets.

My *WebRestController.java*  looks like the below:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders="*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class WebRestController {
    @GetMapping("/summary")
    public String Summary() { /* ... */}
    @GetMapping("/erday")
    public String Erday(String erday) { /* ... */}
    @GetMapping("/count")
    public String Count(@RequestParam Map<String,String> queryParam, 
        String date, String target) { /* ... */}
    @GetMapping("/details")
    public String Details(@RequestParam Map<String,String> queryParam, 
        String date, String target) { /* ... */}
    @GetMapping("/devmawah")
    public String DevMawah(@RequestParam Map<String,String> queryParam, 
        String date, String target) { /* ... */}
    // ....
}
```

I tried before many times in internet to find the solution, but couldn't find it. All I found are examples for Chat applications, which have 2 endpoints to send and receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets are used for bi-directional communication, not really for REST style services (where HTTP is superior in my opinion). The core difference being that HTTP is fundamentally a request-reply protocol, which fits very well to REST whereas WebSocket is centred around messages. Of course, you can argue that request-reply is a specialisation of message-based communication.

There are several articles on this topic (google `REST over WebSocket`) and even some StackOverflow questions which detail the pros and cons, for example  [Is ReST over websockets possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373734/is-rest-over-websockets-possible).

The only way that I know of which allows you to do something resembling REST over WebSocket without having to re-write the RestController is [swagger-socket](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-socket), but I would not recommend using it as the project seems to be inactive now and it seems to not have been used extensively.

Alternatively, you can replace your `@RequestMapping` or `@GetMapping` annotations with [`@MessageMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/MessageMapping.html) annotations and model your API through messages (e.g. the client sends a "GET" message to a given destination, and you send back a message containing the resources).

Answer (score 1):

I can say 99% of reasons that brings us to the idea of `Rest Over Websocket` is just because we are looking at the problems from wrong direction.

But I wrote such library because I am going to need it in another dummy project I will write later, and you can [check it out](https://idioglossia.github.io/spring-rest-over-ws/).

Basically what it does is to scan your controllers, and create a websocket handler that can pass data to those controllers, depending on path, method, and inputs. But there is a lot more it handles internally to achieve this goal.

I havent started the docs yet, so, you can check the sample from website for now.

Comment: Well it depends on the situation... But guess that belongs to the 1%...

Answer (score 0):

Well... Just my little contribution...
First you you should code your websocket handler (taking into account the potential size the payload). Then, you should create a config class to register your hander (I am thinking not in a stomp version).
In your handler, after you stablish the connection with the websocket server, you should have a custom component to hold the sessions (maybe a map of usernames and a session wrapper). This is useful, as you you could send messages not only through the ws connection but also through a rest api endpoint (you could hit an endpoint or using an scheduler tasks to periodically send messages to certain users upon certain conditions). Will post again a link later

Comment: is there any links so far?